# Cakephp echo username into page title

Tags: cakephp, echo, title, assign

I am currently learning Cakephp and have made a profile page of which displays the username on it. You can only access this page when logged in so when you are on this page, I wish to display the username of the user in the HTML page title. This is also because your profile page is visible to other users.

At the moment to get the page headers I have used.

```
<title><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?> | Site Name</title>

<? $this->assign('title', 'Profile')?>
```

And to display the username on the page currently I have:

```
<?php echo $user['User']['user_name']; ?>
```

I have attempted to combine these two into something like shown below but clearly that's not working. Any ideas?

```
<? $this->assign('title', '<?php echo $user['User']['user_name']; ?>')?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake in the concatenation, change this in your .ctp

```
<? $this->assign('title', '<?php echo $user['User']['user_name']; ?>')?>
```

to this

```
<? $this->assign('title', $user['User']['user_name'])?>
```

Later on add this in your layout

`<title><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?> | Site Name</title>`

This will work :)

Comment: That worked perfectly! How would I then go and add a word after the username like 'NAME Profile | Website Name'.

Comment: if it's a static word then go for this:-
<? $this->assign('title', $user['User']['user_name']."PROFILE")?>
else, it's a dynamic word(if you want to use variable)
$profile="PROFILE";
<? $this->assign('title', $user['User']['user_name'].$profile)?>  @leham789